# regular expression string formatting

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Can anyone help with a regex question?
I need to remove all outside white space such that the middle space between alphabet is preserved, and removing the number and special characters that are at the end of a string.

The outputs would have to look something like:

`'  Puerto Rico (#682)  ' -> 'Puerto Rico'`

`'Cote d'Ivoire (#438)' -> 'Cote d'Ivoire'`

I can't seem to preserve the apostrophe and the spaces between the alphabets.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `^` and `$` anchors to ensure that the whitespace and all non-letters are only removed at the start and end of the string:

```
import re
def clean_string(d):
  return re.sub('^\s+|[^a-zA-Z]+$', '', d)

s = ['  Puerto Rico (#682)  ', "Cote d'Ivoire (#438)"]
print([clean_string(i) for i in s])
```

Output:

```
['Puerto Rico', "Cote d'Ivoire"]
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!